# Batch script use sqlite3 to edit settings.db

Tags: settings, shell, languages, scripts, sqlite

I want to create batch script to enable hidden languages in a Huawei phone.
But every time I stuck can you guys spot where is my problem

```
@echo off
color e
cd "%~dp0"
mode con:cols=90 lines=40
adb wait-for-device
adb shell "su -c ' mount -o rw,remount /data'"
adb push sqlite3 /data/local/tmp/sqlite3
adb shell "su -c ' chmod 0755 /data/local/tmp/sqlite3'"
adb shell /data/local/tmp/sqlite3 -batch /data/data/com.android.providers.settings/databases/settings.db "update systemex SET value='ca_ES,en_US,es_US,es_ES,pt_PT,fr_FR,de_DE,it_IT,ar_EG,ar_MA' where name='white_languages'";
```

it give me:

Error: unable to open database `/data/data/com.android.providers.settings/databases/settings.db` : unable to open database file.

Where is the problem and if there is a good way to do it please help me.

Comment: A guess - perhaps the DB file is locked by Settings?

Comment: Why not simply use the `settings` command or `content` command to edit `settings.db`? You wouldn't have to directly access that database file, neither you would need sqlite3.

Comment: @Firelord   can you give an exemple of the commands ?

Comment: first time to hear about the settings or the content command but a come accross one before run it but fail :  `adb shell settings put systemex white_languages ca_ES,en_US,es_US,es_ES,pt_PT,fr_FR,de_DE,it_IT,ar_EG,ar_MA`     it give me :    `/system/bin/sh: settings: not found`

Comment: i realy need a deferent aproach : the settings isnt in the android 4.1.1 phone am working on it but exist in an LG 4.4.2 i have so if we can have a solution that can change the settings in settings.db that can work across deferent versions of android at least from 4 to up.